# How can I print out the results of this json file? (Android Retrofit2)

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

I want to show Json result in textview using retrofit2, but I can't get the desired result.

**json**

```
    {
  "rows" : [ {
    "playerId" : "f8a49812eb9c3e5c8e738c3664e0ebd1",
    "nickname" : "Yuichuan",
    "grade" : 89
  } ]
}
```

**Model.class**

```
public class Model {
    public String playerId;
    public String nickname;
    public int grade;

    public String getPlayerId() {
        return playerId;
    }

    public void setPlayerId(String playerId) {
        this.playerId = playerId;
    }

    public String getNickname() {
        return nickname;
    }

    public void setNickname(String nickname) {
        this.nickname = nickname;
    }

    public int getGrade() {
        return grade;
    }

    public void setGrade(int grade) {
        this.grade = grade;
    }
}
```

**PlayerModel.class**

```
    public class PlayerModel {
    public List<Model> rows;
}

**RetrofitFactory.class**

    public class RetrofitFactory {
    private static String BASE_URL="https://api.neople.co.kr/";
    public static RetrofitService create(){
        Retrofit retrofit=new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL).addConverterFactory(GsonC`enter code here`onverterFactory.create()).build();
        return retrofit.create(RetrofitService.class);
    }
}
```

**RetrofitService.interface**

```
    public interface RetrofitService {
    @GET("cy/players/")
    Call<PlayerModel> getlist(@Query("nickname") String nickname,
                              @Query("apikey") String apikey);
}
```

**MainActivityt**

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String API_KEY = "8yTuVMwy2DirHl2sWaZ3C8IJLslOfTpQ";
    private static final String TAG ="Main" ;
    TextView textView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textView=findViewById(R.id.test);
        RetrofitService networkService=RetrofitFactory.create();
        networkService.getlist("Yuichuan",API_KEY)
                .enqueue(new Callback<PlayerModel>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<PlayerModel> call, Response<PlayerModel> response) {
                            if(!response.isSuccessful()){
                                textView.setText(response.code());
                                return;
                            }
                        Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: ConfigurationListener::"+call.request().url());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<PlayerModel> call, Throwable t) {
                        textView.setText(t.getMessage());
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

I want to print out these json files, but it doesn't work as I want, so I want you to give me some help or advice.It seems like a simple problem, but it is very difficult for me because I am not used to json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `textView.setText(response.code());` give you a code of response. To get your data model you need a body of response `response.body()`

Comment: List<Model> abcd=response.body().rows;
                            String playerId=abcd.get(0).getPlayerId();
                            String nickname=abcd.get(0).getNickname();
                            int grade=abcd.get(0).getGrade();

Comment: This way, it was solved. I'm sorry. I posted a question and kept trying and it was a success.